# pygame pacman I want to know the meaning of the code

Tags: pygame

It's a function that got Ghost to follow player, but I don't understand.
I want to know the meaning of the code.

```py
def followPlayer(g, dirs):  
    d = ghosts[g].dir 
    if d == 1 or d == 3:
        if player.x > ghosts[g].x and dirs[0] == 1: ghosts[g].dir = 0
        if player.x < ghosts[g].x and dirs[2] == 1: ghosts[g].dir = 2
    if d == 0 or d == 2:
        if player.y > ghosts[g].y and dirs[1] == 1 and not aboveCentre(ghosts[g]): ghosts[g].dir = 1
        if player.y < ghosts[g].y and dirs[3] == 1: ghosts[g].dir = 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code determines the direction of movement of the ghost. The movement is encoded in `ghosts[g].dir`. 0 means right, 2 means left, 1 means down and 3 means up.

If the movement of the ghost is vertical (`if d == 1 or d == 3`), then it is evaluated if the movement direction has to be changed to a horizontal direction (0, 2).
If the movement of the ghost is horizontal (`if d == 0 or d == 2:`), then it is evaluated if the movement direction has to be changed to a vertical direction (1, 3).

If the movement to certain direction is allowed is stored in the list `dirs`.

For instance, the meaning of the following lines of code is:

```
if d == 1 or d == 3:
    if player.x > ghosts[g].x and dirs[0] == 1: ghosts[g].dir = 0
```

- if the movement is vertical (`if d == 1 or d == 3:`)
- and the player is at the right of the ghost (`player.x > ghosts[g].x`)
- and the movement to the right is allowed `dirs[0] == 1`
- then change the direction of movement to the right `ghosts[g].dir = 0`